# Dse opscenter is not starting Up

Tags: cassandra

I Have added the below lines in /usr/share/opscenter/bin/opscenter script:

OPSC_JVM_OPTS="-server -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dpython.cachedir.skip=false
                -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
                -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
                -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
                -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -Xloggc:$OPSC_GC_LOG_PATH/gc.log
                $OPSC_JVM_OPTS"
OPSC_JVM_OPTS="$OPSC_JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/opscenter/tmp"

Comment: still dse opscenter is not starting up, i am getting below error :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/twistd", line 94, in <module>
    from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.application import app
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 17, in <module>
from twisted.application import service, reactors
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/service.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import defer

Comment: File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/python/lockfile.py", line 23, in <module>
    from os import kill
ImportError: cannot import name kill

Comment: Please help on this.

Comment: Have you changed original opscenter script? just please compare both the file it seems there is some syntax mismatch.

Comment: Thanks...issue got resolved